# issues storing and extracting arrays in numpy file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Trying to store an array in numpy file however, while trying to extract it, and use it, getting an error message as trying to apply array to a sequence.

These are the two arrays, unsure which one is causing the issue.

```
X = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6....]
```

while trying to retrieve it and use it getting the values as:

```
X: array(list[1,2,3],list[4,5,6],list[7,8,9])
y = array([0,1,2,3,4,5...])
```

Here is the code:

```
vectors = np.array(X)
labels = np.array(y)
```

While retrieving working on t-sne

```
visualisations = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(X,y)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-244f99341167> in <module>()
----> 1 visualisations = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(X,y)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\t_sne.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    856             Embedding of the training data in low-dimensional space.
    857         """
--> 858         embedding = self._fit(X)
    859         self.embedding_ = embedding
    860         return self.embedding_

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\t_sne.py in _fit(self, X, skip_num_points)
    658         else:
    659             X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
--> 660                             dtype=[np.float32, np.float64])
    661         if self.method == 'barnes_hut' and self.n_components > 3:
    662             raise ValueError("'n_components' should be inferior to 4 for the "

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the vital piece of code which you use to store and read the NumPy file. Can you share this with us?

Comment: Be sure to show `X` before saving (the `repr` is more informative than the `str`).  Also how are you `extracting` and `using`.   Show the exact code that is producing the error message (with `traceback` if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly you need to package the first group in a list; something like this:

```
import numpy as np

#X = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
#y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9]

X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
y = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array(list[1,2,3],list[4,5,6],list[7,8,9])
```

is a 1d object dtype array.  To get that from

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

requires more than `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`; either the list elements have to vary in size, or you have to initialize an object array and copy the list values to it.

In any case `fit_transform` cannot handle that kind of array.  It expects a 2d numeric dtype. Notice the parameters to the `check_array` function.

If all the list elements of `X` are the same size, then

```
X = np.stack(X)
```

should turn it into a 2d numeric array.

I suspect `X` was that 1d object array type before saving.  By itself `save/load` should not turn a 2d numeric array into an object one.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your option, 'X = np.stack(X)'
 then I get an error: **'ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape'**

Comment: That means, contrary to your example, that the lists in `X` vary in size.  That explains why `X` is object dtype.  It can't make a 2d array from a ragged list of lists.  You'll have to address that variable length issue before using `sklearn`.